# mamba screwed up my conda environments, how to uninstall mamba?

Tags: conda

After installing mamba, my conda environments are messed up like this:

```
# conda environments:
#
base                     /Users/USERNAME/mambaforge
                         /Users/USERNAME/opt/anaconda3
                      *  /Users/jlee/opt/anaconda3/envs/NLP
```

I don't like this. How do I uninstall mamba to fix this? Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue!
Mamba rerouted your base environment to /Users/USERNAME/mambaforge instead of the usual location -- /Users/USERNAME/opt/anaconda3

In order to fix the problem, you have to edit your shell initialization file (bashrc, bash_profile, or etc).
Add this line to it to export the original filepath of your anaconda3 environment to your PATH. \

```
export PATH="/Users/USERNAME/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
```